# How to handle App version while your newer vesion is in review?

Tags: react-native, version-control, backend, release-management

I am new to version controlling and managing. I am in a situation where my current application is published and users are using it.
We have a new version, which we want to submit for review but for that we need to upload new version of backend to cloud and it wont work for older version  and if we wont upload newe version then it wont work for reviewer.

How to resolve this issue ? Or Better implementation suggestions. Thank you

FrontEnd:- ReactNative
Backend:- Node and Express
Query Language for API: GraphQL
Cloud: Microsoft Azure.

Dont know how to resolve this

Comment: One was is to release the backend api with new version, with v2 in the base url for the changed apis

Answer (score 0):

ok. for this. you have solution. you have to create a new api with v2 and run it. same put a static value on backend and Front-End for example

```
APP_VERSION = 1.
```

Now Create an API where it we'll get version from backend. if version number or different the show a message to user that please update the application.

for example. if we have uploaded new version to backend

```
APP_VERSION = 1.1
```

and user have app with

```
APP_VERIOSN 1.1
```

then show a message that please update to latest version

Comment: Thank You. My app version 1 is compatible with backend version 1. App is published and working completely fine. 
Now We have developed app version 2 and for that we have updated some queries response and request type. Now the situation is if i will create container and upload to production it will not work for App version1. So how i can submit my app version 2 under review for  respective stores ?

Comment: for version 2 you can create a server and after version 2 is live then delete your first server. in app version 2 you have to force user to update .

Comment: okay. we have already implementation that will check app current version and google store version, if its higher than current then they are forced to update app version.
So, every time when we will have new version and some updates in backend, we have to create a server and delete the old one?

Comment: yes. we have already two server one for testing and second is for release.

Comment: so, when you submit your application for review, is it pointing testing env? or release env? if it is pointed to testing env and once they approve it how you are changing that to release env?